# Device doesn't work, simulator does

Tags: objective-c, ios, upload, ftp, ios-simulator

What would cause code to execute on the simulator, but not execute properly on the device?

I'm uploading a file to a server via ftp. I'm using `http://code.google.com/p/s7ftprequest/` to do the uploading. Is there a simpler way to upload via ftp?

I've tried cleaning targets and resetting everything, but that doesn't help.

```
//create file for new submission
[submission.text writeToURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.txt", submissionNum] atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

//create new number.txt file
NSString *numberFileString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",submissionNum];
[numberFileString writeToURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"number.txt"] atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

//connect and upload submission
S7FTPRequest *ftpRequest = [[S7FTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://cheekyapps.com/ezhighasiam"]
                                                toUploadFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.txt", submissionNum]];
```

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: I don't get an exception, but I get (Cocoa Error 260). I can't find any info on the error

Comment: did u see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547075/cocoa-contentsofdirectoryatpath-method-failing-with-error-for-certain-users-ma ?

Comment: or this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400216/array-of-nsstrings-from-filenames-within-a-folder

Comment: Nope, but that second one looks like exactly what I need. Thank youu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Googeling](http://www.google.de/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Cocoa+Error+260)&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=NMRJTannFsvEswa_mt2NDw#sclient=psy&hl=de&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&source=hp&q=Cocoa+Error+260&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=55b53f790fed0d4c) "Cocoa Error 260" let me think, that you are using a path, the device doesn't understand. Maybe with ~ or a path that doesnt work with the sandboxing.

Show some code and we can tell more.

**edit**

You need to construct a Path to the applications doucument folder in it sandbox. [This post might be a start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202988/iphone-storing-and-then-reading-a-file-from-documents-folder/2203058#2203058).

in short: To access the Documents folder you should do

**edit**
This writes your file to the documents folder

```
NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSSting *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", %d.txt]];
[submission.text writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

with the same filePath you can feed your ftp-request

Comment: I just posted what I think is causing the problem.. It's creating two files, and then uploading them

Comment: I'm not sure. They're where ever they get saved to when you programmatically create files. I'm still new to Obj-C

Comment: in that case verify that you are not writing to the bundle (think of it as the package of the app). That will break the provisioning.

Comment: Save everything to the Documents folder or similair. and use the 'NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains' to construct the path

Comment: So would I do something like ` NSString* docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"number.txt"];`

Comment: Ahhh I'd hug you if I could. That worked!! THank you so much!!

Comment: Depending on ur timezone: go to the street and hug the next person u see. It could be me. Bad idea, if it is night...

Comment: BTW: Try to start using CoreData as soon as possible. Persistency gets much easier with it (although the filesystem might be the better place for binary data).

Answer (score 2):

The [Foundations Constants Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html) indicates that 260 is NSFileReadNoSuchFileError.